# Flex make image full screen

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

when i run the image, it only appear in center with 2 blank white space in between.

```
<s:Image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" source="@Embed('assets/d.jpg')"/>
```

How can i make an image goes full screen (covering up the whole screen) with double tap/touch on mobile app?

And if possible how to turn it back to non-full screen (back to normal)?

thanks.

*image size: W=1920, H=1200*

[image]

Comment: Is it more complicated than changing the height and width of the image?  What problem are you having accomplishing this?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com question adjusted, please refer above. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the white bars you're going to have set the [scaleMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#scaleMode) of the Image tag.  The default is Letterbox; which is what you appear to be using.

If you set it to stretch then it will fill the space, without the white border.  However, it may distort the image by not maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: very good, now i know have to had a picture with a better aspect ratio so it can stretch better.  thank for info.

Comment: @jameslcs Depending what you're trying to do; it is not uncommon to use a different graphical asset for each of the different DPI resolutions that Flex Mobile supports.  Most tablets are 160; most phones are 240; and the iPhone 4 is 320.

Comment: do i need to make different app for different phone/tablets? is there a better way, what is your solution? thanks

Comment: @jameslcs You don't have to; but you can do so at your own discretion.  Flex exposes an applicationDPI variable you can use to decide which assets to use at runtime.

Comment: @ www.Flextras.com btw how to set the image width = screen width, without white border in between the width (as my setting of width=100% is not working).

Comment: Normally you wouldn't care about screen width; you'd focus on the application's width.  How to access that depends on your setup.  If you're having problem, you should post another question w/ more details than can be provided in a comment; as this thread no longer appears applicable to the current question.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:
Mobile devices come with different screen sizes. And we need an image to look good across different screen sizes (Android + iPhone + iPad + iPod, etc.).

**One Solution**:
I recently had to deal with this issue and found that this worked well for me.

```
<s:BitmapImage id="image"
        source="@Embed('assets/images/background_startup.png')" 
        width="100%" height="100%" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
        scaleMode="zoom" horizontalAlign="center"/>
```

Now as you can see this eliminates the white border's while maintaining aspect ratio. If you are developing a splash image (like the ones you see at the beginning of most application startups) this is a really simple way of taking care of it. Mind that you will have to develop a multi-screen compatible image, or assign a properly scaled image depending on the screen size. If you just want to develop ONE image, a good size that currently employ is 700px wide and 1200px tall. Why so much taller? Because most high-res devices use this screen size (lets consider this the max resolution). At the same time, developing an image that is significantly taller than it is wide helps us control which parts of the image are cropped if a smaller screen size requires it. Mind you this model only works if your app is running in **portrait** only.

[image]

As you can see above we have a "safe" zone and an "unsafe" are we can expect to be cropped. From what I've found this area is about 100 to 110px tall and should not include important text or information but still includes the background and borders so everything still looks good.

**Moto Droid Pro**

[image: Moto Droid Pro]

**Moto Droid X**

[image]

**iPhone 3GS**

[image]

Hope this helps!