# How to scale an image to the full screen using Flex/Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, image

I am still struggling with transforming my app build in Java/Eclipse to Flex/Actionscript with Flashbuilder.
Now I can not find how I should implement an image to cover the hole screen.
In my current app I used relative layout and

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/rubrik"
    />
```

but I do not find how I shall define this in Flex views.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166988/flex-make-image-full-screen).

You need to modify the **scaleMode** property of the [Image spark tag (as documented here).](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#scaleMode)

```
<s:Image scaleMode="BitmapScaleMode.STRETCH" x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" source="@Embed('assets/example.jpg')"/>
```

You can play with either BitmapScaleMode.STRETCH, BitmapScaleMode.ZOOM, or  BitmapScaleMode.LETTERBOX.